# Error in Postman while invoking HES Impact API

Tags: api, postman

While invoking API in Postman it fails giving below error. It works fine when invoked from APIM. I have tried troubleshooting with Sean Osejo but we couldn't resolve it. Below is the **Test** API operation that I am trying to invoke
HES --> Incident Management - First Report Creation --> Post Login User

[Please refer this link in teams for error screenshot and parameters passed](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19:36f144b5fb46461c891d7402f843b4da@thread.skype/1576639501061?tenantId=fd799da1-bfc1-4234-a91c-72b3a1cb9e26&groupId=f768c467-a9ca-4fa9-ba5a-0f2d5c6bc66c&parentMessageId=1576639501061&teamName=API%20%26%20Integration%20COP&channelName=General&createdTime=1576639501061)

While troubleshooting we have tried disabling Proxy and SSL settings but still no luck

Error Message
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://apim-test1.azure.chevron.com/hes/incident-management-oeimpact/v1/api/security/login?id=****&token=*********.
Why this might have happened:
-The server couldn't send a response: Ensure that the backend is working properly
-Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked: Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
-Proxy configured incorrectly Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
-Request timeout: Change request timeout in Settings > General

Error in Postman console:
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.243.78.102:443

Comment: Please put the text of the error message in the question itself.

Comment: Error message added in the question